# I can't execute sqlite statement when running code normally, but in debug mode it works. How is it possible?

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I have a SQLite database connected via JDBC to my java project. I can easily read all the data and add a new user to my database, however when I execute a prepared statement i get an SQLexeption. And after I run the program in debug mode and set a breakpoint to the line with the prepared statement, it does the task without any problem.

I tried switching up the code, and all other statements work, for example INSERT, or SELECT. Only UPDATE (in any kind of form) does not work. I tried to execute the statement in sql command line and it worked, so there isn't the problem.

```java
public void makeReq(int type,String SPZ){
        String sql = "UPDATE users "
                + "SET req = ? "
                + "WHERE SPZ = ?";
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:users.db");
            PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql); 
            pstmt.setInt(1, type);
            pstmt.setString(2, SPZ);
            int rowAffected = pstmt.executeUpdate();


        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("FATAL ERROR: couldn't connect to the USERS database");
        }
    }
```

I expect it to execute and update the selected table(users).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Print the SQLException and not your custom message.

Comment: It says that the database is busy, but when I delete the line with the connection it says that the connection is closed.

Comment: Can you edit your question and paste the stack trace that you see?

Comment: I found the problem, posted it as an answer. Thank you for your help tough, I wouldn't have found that is I didn´t read the SQLExeption.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer: I had my database opened somewhere else in my project, I tought I deleted that but I didn't.